# Erro ao pegar o array por indice

Tags: php, array, foreach

Tenho esse codigo e não sei por que esta me retornando apenas o primeiro caracter da variavel(exe: se no login conter o valor Diego,imprime apenas D)
O print_r que esta ali,coloquei para testar o retorno toda a informação que preciso esta ali no array.

Peço desculpas se não foi a pergunta mais elaborada.

```
<table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>idSessao</td>
                <td>Modelo</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $idSessao = $_SESSION['login']['uid'];
                $modelObj->get_dados_venda_club($idSessao);
                $lista = $modelObj->data;

                print_r($lista);
                if(!isset($lista)){
                    foreach ($lista as $key => $listas) {
                ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $listas['idSessao']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $listas['modelo']?></td>
                    </tr>

                <?php       
                     }
                }else{
                    echo "não existe retorno ".$listas;
                }
            ?>
        </table>
```

// retorno com var_dump

array(7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "13" ["modelo"]=> string(4) "1564" ["login"]=> string(28) "faco ideia do que entra aqui" ["senha"]=> string(8) "88274574" ["cadin"]=> string(10) "1459800190" ["status"]=> string(1) "1" ["idSessao"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: Coloca na pergunta a estrutura do array

Comment: Para ficar mais claro, você poderia executar um `var_dump($lista)` e postar aqui o resultado .. Assim ficará mais facil ajudar.

Comment: Talvez no banco de dados você não definiu o tamanho da string, por isso pode estar salvando apenas a primeira letra. Ou o tipo, por exemplo, char ou varchar.